# "Cannot resolve method - candidates are" - compilation error

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Recently , i created new class that suppose to wrap each method i want to use and retry use if it fails.

To make this feature available for various kinds of method from one parameter to five and more, i created some method overloads.

Trying to use this method in some cases gave me the compilation error:
"Cannot resolve method - candidates are"
and i wanted to get some advises about ways to handle it.

So, here is an example of two methods:

```
 public static TResult Do<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> action, T param,
                                                RetryIntervals retryInterval, int retryIntervalMultiplier = 0, int retryCount = 3)

 public static TResult Do<T, T2, TResult>(Func<T, T2, TResult> action, T param, T2 param2,
                                                    RetryIntervals retryInterval , int retryIntervalMultiplier = 0, int retryCount = 3)
```

If i use this new feature this way:

```
RetryProcess.Do(CacheManager.ExecuteSet, key, value,RetryProcess.RetryIntervals.TenMilliSeconds);
```

I get the error i mentioned above.

The only solutions i thought about until now are:

- Use all the parameters in each call without default parameters (do not like it because i need the default parameters to make the code cleaner).
- Each "Do" method will have different name depend on how many parameters it has (also feels it is not a good solution and miss the overload idea).

Do you have some other ideas for me?

Comment: In general, it best not to mix overloading methods with default parameters. Instead, if you are overloading, add more overloads without the parameters and then just have them call the relevant method with that default value. I don't know if this is your issue, just something I spotted

Comment: How is `CacheManager.ExecuteSet` defined?

Comment: public static bool ExecuteSet(string key, object value, ExpirationTimeEnum expirationTime = ExpirationTimeEnum.Never)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the signature of

```
 public static bool ExecuteSet(string key, object value, ExpirationTimeEnum expirationTime = ExpirationTimeEnum.Never) { return true; }
```

is only compatible to:

```
TFunc<T, T1, T2, TResult>
```

So there are no problems with the default parameters of `Do(...)` or their parameters, but with definition of `ExecuteSet(...)`.

*What are your additional possibilites?*

1. do an *ugly workaround*:

   ```
   Do((_, __) => ExecuteSet(_, __), key, value, RetryIntervals.TenMilliSeconds);
   ```
2. *add just another overload* for the `ExecuteSet` method and remove the default parameter there:

   ```
   public static bool ExecuteSet(string key, object value) {
       return ExecuteSet(key, value, ExpirationTimeEnum.Never);
   }

   public static bool ExecuteSet(string key, object value, ExpirationTimeEnum expirationTime) { /* ... */ }
   ```

   This should not change semantics and lets you compile your initial method call:

   ```
   Do(CacheManager.ExecuteSet, key, value,RetryProcess.RetryIntervals.TenMilliSeconds);
   ```

Additional thoughts about default parameters can be found on [Eric Lipperts blog](https://ericlippert.com/2011/05/16/optional-argument-corner-cases-part-three/).